# PHP Trouble Configuring SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am working on learning PHP, and one of my goals is to be able to connect to an SQL Server database.  I am on a virtual Windows 2008 Server and have 32-bit PHP 5.6.0 installed. I have downloaded the `sqlsrv` drivers and put them into `C:\PHP\ext`. The drivers in there are `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv.dll`.

I restarted the web server (and the VM too), and `phpinfo` still doesn't list the `sqlsrv` section.  I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

I have looked at issues with 64-bit vs 32-bit, but I don't understand all of it.  If anyone has any thoughts or can help me to troubleshoot this, I would love to get past configuration and start building PHP pages!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the requisite entries into php.ini?

Comment: yep.  I checked my builds and all.  These are the dynamic extensions: extension=php_wincache.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Comment: I also have extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext" and I have verified that all dlls are in that directory.

Comment: When I run php.exe I get this: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: wincache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS,VC11
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS,VC11
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION for php_sqlsrv: entering
PHP_RINIT for php_sqlsrv: entering
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors = On
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = -1
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = -1
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 10240

Answer (score 0):

It is a module incompatibility. Your PHP is the Thread-Safe version, and the wincache module requires the Non-Thread-Safe version.

You must either remove the wincache extension, or install the non-thread-safe version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I just see this when I run the php.exe : PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION for php_sqlsrv: entering
PHP_RINIT for php_sqlsrv: entering
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors = On
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = -1
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = -1
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 10240
  I still don't see any sqlsrv section in the phpinfo()  I restart web services, but nothing.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` output? Also, what does `php -v` output?

Comment: I commented out the wincache, and when I start php.exe console, I see what I put in the above comment.  when I type php -v and hit enter, nothing happens.  Same when I type phpinfo() .  It sounds like I need to clean up the vm and uninstall stuff, so I can install compatible components, etc.  What I am unsure of is the reason or purpose of choosing ts or nts.  It sounds like I should uninstall ts php and install nts, but non-thread safe sounds like a bad way to run processes, unless I am missing something.  Thanks for all your comments!